# How to redirect back to the checkout page in prestashop?

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules

I am building a site using prestashop and I am having a problem with redirection at checkout page.When I am at checkout page and I choose paypal or satispay and whenever I click cancel to one of between paypal or satispay the website goes to the cart page instead of going back to the checkout. Any idea how can I fix this? What's the file or module responsible that does redirecting?

Answer (score 0):

In short, this depends on the module you are using and the module code needs to be reviewed.